# What will the Terran Point Defence Drone work against?

Tags: starcraft-2

Regarding the Terran Raven unit, and its Point Defence Drone (PDD), what unit attacks will be intercepted by the PDD?

I haven't been able to find a complete list.

Comment: Can you please devise a more relevant title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the [Starcraft Wikia](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Point_defense_drone):

> The drone intercepts missiles and projectiles fired by certain enemy
>   units and buildings. According to the in-game description of the
>   point-defense laser it is effective against marauders, vikings,
>   banshees, battlecruisers, thors, missile turrets, stalkers, phoenixes,
>   photon cannons, queens, mutalisks, corruptors, hydralisks, and spore
>   crawlers.
>
> Its defensive abilities use up 10 energy per shot. Units like vikings
>   and phoenixes that attack twice or more per cycle will drain 10 energy
>   for each of its individual attacks (i.e. 1 viking attack consists of 2
>   missiles. 20 energy would be consumed to intercept both missiles).

Comment: Nice clear and clean answer +1 from me

Comment: It *doesn't* work on Hydralisk melee attack, I think.

Comment: It doesn't work on *any* melee attacks...

Comment: lol he said hydralisk and melee attack in the same sentence...

Comment: Hydralisk has a melee animation which is different than its missile animation, so I can understand why one would say that. But don't be deceived; the projectile properties still remain (including for example upgrades and PDD)